# Unable to apply publish properties?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, warnings

I don't know what caused Visual Studio to start thinking it needs to publish my project, but now whenever I build it, I get several "Unable to apply publish properties for item 'blah'" warnings. How do I stop [Visual Studio 2005](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2005)'s publishing facilities from working on my project completely? I use [InstallShield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InstallShield), so I don't have any use for Visual Studio's publishing system.

Comment: What warning error codes are they?

Comment: It doesn't have one. Here's the warning: http://i42.tinypic.com/210cbae.png

Comment: This happened to me after I cleaned up some unnecessary assembly references - the application files ClickOnce settings are not kept in synch automatically and require this attention.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Open your project, select Project Properties->Publish(ing)->Application Files and click the reset all button. Does that help?

Comment: In case anyone lease wanders across this. I had a similar problem but didn't want to just reset all because I wanted to preserve the previous settings. So in the Application Files dialog, I checked "show on files" and it showed me missing files with a warning icon so I could delete manually.

Comment: I second yieldvs's comments, I would recommend not resetting all of them, instead click the 'Show all files' and select your reference.

Comment: The reset-all button didn't help. After closing/re-opening the solution and re-running the application, the warnings return. @yieldvs' solution works.

Comment: Reset All appears to work only on the files that are currently shown in the dialog. In other words, you should probably tick Show All Files before hitting the reset button.

Comment: Before reading comments and deleting manually I found that I had to click 'reset all' multiple times.  After clicking about 5 times my warnings are gone.

Comment: For me, the project name had been changed.  A previous developer had included the PDB files in the click once install, but the old name was still listed on the name of the PDB file to include for the main application.

Answer (score 10):

In Project Properties > Publish > Application Files...

If you click "Show All" you will see that some items have a yellow exclamation mark indicating that those files are no longer referenced. Just delete these entries.

[image]