# ClickOnce not publishing every language

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, azure-devops, clickonce

I am currently trying to publish an application via ClickOnce.

I tried to add a new language (nds-DE) and it works, when I compile it locally.
But when I try to build it using tfs-online it just leaves it out.

If I try set the "Application File"-Settings to include, I just get the warning

`Warning MSB3331: Unable to apply publish properties for item "nds-de\dsacharactersheet.core.resources"`

Does anyone have an Idea how to fix this?

Project: [DSACharacterSheet](https://github.com/lightlike/DSACharacterSheet)

Comment: Not sure if this will be helpful but check out this solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9295229/2174170) or [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/989868/2174170)

Comment: @Dumisani Nope. It works and also shows locally. I think the Problem is with the Hosted tfs Build Agent.

Comment: What're tasks of build definition? Can you share the detail build log on the OneDrive (Set system.debug variable to true and queue build)? How do you add nds-DE language (there isn't dns-DE in Publish>Options>Description>Publish language)? How do you set “application File" settings to include?

Comment: @starain-MSFT The .resx is at DSACharacterSheet.Core/Lang in the given Project. The last Log where this error occured is [here](https://pastebin.com/0FcNMWkT) (Warning in line 120).  Publish language sould be none, because is sould be published in multiple languages.  And I set the Application Files in Publish from Auto to Include.

Comment: Can you provide the detail steps of how to add language?

Comment: @starain-MSFT I just add a new embedded Resource File to DSACharacterSheet.Core/Lang.

Comment: Then how do you specify that language in Publish option?

Comment: @starain-MSFT Look at [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5447/NET-Localization-using-Resource-file) and the LocalizationManager Class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSTS hosted agent are running on Windows Server OS which does not support "nds-de" culture, the workaround is configuring a private build agent on Win 10 OS to run the build.

Comment: That was what I suspected. I will try that when I install a new OS on my server.